# How to receive posts from Instagram API using Express.js on Node

Tags: node.js, express, instagram

I am trying to set up an app that will show Instagram posts in real time with a certain hashtag.

Here's what I have thus far.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
  , connect = require('connect')
  , $ = require('jquery')
//  , ngrok = require('ngrok')
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//ngrok.connect(5000, function (err, url) {

//})

app.listen(port);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  res.writeHead(500);
  return res.end('Error loading index.html');
}

res.writeHead(200);
res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.emit('stuff', function() {
    console.log("http server listening on %d", port);
  });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

});

// Defining Routes

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Testing');

});

app.get('/endpoint', function (req, res) { 
  // For convention's sake, we only respond to this if it's a properly formatted request from Instagram
  if (req.query['hub.challenge']) {
    // First we check if hub.challenge exists in the query, then we do something
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  }
});
```

This is where I'm wrong/lost

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/endpoint', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

I believe I've followed the Subscription tutorial in the Instagram API (set up hub.challenge and set up a subscription) but how do I see the incoming JSON data it's supposed to send? On top of that, how can I manipulate the JSON to show the pictures on the front end?

Any help is appreciated!